# Can't read array state properly when using useState hook in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

What I'm trying to implement is [snackbar](https://m2.material.io/components/snackbars#usage) widget that renders a stack of popup messages.

However, when I try to modify an array of message data objects, React starts to behave weird: each time I try to add an object, the old array appears to be empty, yet the last toast message is rendered to the page.

[I made a demo for this issue](https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-hofstadter-hf7mrk?file=/src/App.js), and below is the code. I'm checking the state before setting and one second after, and it's always an empty array, yet the last added toast always appears on screen.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function showToast(message) {
  const tData = { message: message, timestamp: Date.now() };
  const event = new CustomEvent("custom_toast", { detail: tData });
  window.dispatchEvent(event);
}

function Toast({ message, index }) {
  const style = {
    position: "absolute",
    left: "2vw",
    bottom: `calc(1vw + 5.5vw * ${index})`,

    backgroundColor: "magenta",
    color: "black",
    height: "5vw"
  };

  return (
    <div className="toast" style={style}>
      {message}
    </div>
  );
}

let effectFuze = true;

export default function App() {
  const [toasts, setToasts] = useState([]);

  function addToast(tData) {
    console.log("State before set");
    console.log(toasts);

    // Someone suggested you have to copy
    // object inside array too (i call bs)

    // const cloned = toasts.map((t) => ({ ...t }));
    // cloned.push(tData);
    // setToasts(cloned);
    setToasts([...toasts, tData]);
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("State after set");
      console.log(toasts);
    }, 1000);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!effectFuze) return;
    effectFuze = false;
    window.addEventListener("custom_toast", (e) => addToast(e.detail));
  });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1 onClick={() => showToast("toast!")}>show toast</h1>
      <div>{`There are ${
        document.querySelectorAll(".toast").length
      } toasts on this page`}</div>

      {toasts.map((t, i) => (
        <Toast key={t.timestamp} message={t.message} index={i} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: It seems like replacing setToast(...) with setToast(prev => [...prev, tData]) solves the issue, but I'm still confused why that happens and why I can't read toasts directly

Comment: [Understanding PrevState in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73993973/understanding-prevstate-in-react).

Comment: Actually, the issue was caused because I was setting the event listener only on first effect. Returning cleanup callback from effect solves the issue, as [discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55817787/access-state-from-event-handler-created-within-react-js-useeffect-hook)